# unable to create bootable iso from bin file

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, bios

I have been recently trying to create a simple bootloader and this is some simple code I have come up with to start. When I compile it with nasm to a binary file, I am able to load it just fine with `qemu-system-x86_64 boot.bin`.

I tried to use the dd command to create a bootable iso image from the binary file, but the code does not do the expected outcome (where you can freely type anything on your keyboard and it will print to the screen) in something like vmware.

I am using Debian 11.

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
loop:
mov ah, 0x00 ; tty mode
int 0x16
mov ah, 0x0e
int 0x10

jmp loop 

; padding and magic number
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: How are you creating a bootable ISO (CD-ROM image) from a bin file using DD?

Comment: As well as answering that question, when you run it on VMWare what does it do when it fails?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, It doesn't run as expected in something like vmware, it allows me to press a key and it does print, but when I press more keys it does not print to the screen as expected. Its supposed to print any keys I press to the screen.

Comment: What exactly are the commands you are using to build this ISO image? You give code but don't show how you turn it into an ISO image so it is rather hard to tell if your are making an error somewhere in the process that is causing an issue.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing incorrectly, I was straight up dumping the entire bootloader directly with dd command rather than creating an empty iso with /dev/zero.

rather than doing:
dd if=/dev/zero of=keyboardimg.iso bs=512 count=1440;
dd if=keyboard.bin of=keyboardimg.iso bs=512 seek=0 count=1

Comment: ISO is a term used for CD-ROM images which are different things altogether, you are creating disk images.